# Throwing a ball causes Earth to move away

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, earth

I understand that the Earth "falls" towards the ball on its descent, as a result of the attractive gravitational force on the two. However, I've been stuck on trying to explain the reverse scenario; why the Earth "moves away" from the ball after it is thrown upwards. Can someone mathematically explain this situation?

Comment: The Earth moves for the same reason that the ball moves:  You push on them:  You push on the Earth with your feet at the same time you are pushing on the ball (i.e., throwing it) with your hand.

Answer (score 4):

Cricket balls and baseballs have a mass of about $0.15 \,\rm kg$.

Suppose a ball is thrown upwards from rest with a velocity of $20\,\rm m/s$ then the ball suffers a change in momentum of $0.15 \times 20 =3\,\rm N\,s$.

Now looking at the ball and the Earth as a system which has no external forces acting on it, the momentum of the ball and Earth system must be conserved.
So the change in upward momentum of the ball, $3\,\rm N\,s$ must be same as the change in the downward momentum of the Earth.
The Earth started from rest and if $v_{\rm Earth}$ is its final downward (opposite in direction to that of the ball) velocity then ${\rm mass}_{\rm Earth} \times v_{\rm Earth} = 3$.

The mass of the Earth is $6\times 10^{24}\,\rm kg$ and so the velocity of the Earth is $5\times 10^{-25}\,\rm m/s$.

Answer (score 0):

- The Earth is attracted to the ball because of gravity, yes. This force is **attractive** regardless of the motion direction. When the ball flies upwards, the Earth is still attracted upwards by $\vec F_g$.
- When you through the ball upwards, then we are looking at another phenomenon: **Newton's 3rd law**. The push $\vec F_p$ upwards on the ball implies a downwards push $\vec F_p$ on the Earth.

Whichever of these two forces $\vec F_p$ and $\vec F_g$ have the largest influence, determine the resulting motion and direction of the Earth (this is Newton's 2nd law).

Many other effects, such as you neighbour picking up a tray of plates, must be included as well, though. Although all this is insanely negligible...

Answer (score 0):

Newton's Third Law:

(Notation in case it is not clear, $\vec{F_{ba}}$ is the force $a$ exerts on $b$.)

Given two objects $a$ and $b$, $\vec{F_{ba}} = - \vec{F_{ab}}$.

Also, you can do this using conservation of momentum:

Let's way oversimplify here and assume that the earth (plus me, ignored for simplicity since I'm gravitationally stuck to the earth), the ball are all at rest from our reference frame.  Since Newtonian momentum is defined as $\vec{p} = m\vec{v}$ and since all objects in our system are at rest, $\vec{p}_{total} = 0 \boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{r}}}$. After applying the force, $\vec{p}_{ball} \ne 0$.  However, due to conservation of momentum, $\vec{p}_{total} = \vec{p}_{earth} + \vec{p}_{ball} = 0$, so we can solve for the earth's momentum and get $\vec{p}_{earth} = -\vec{p}_{ball}$.